# Do not apply brackets to a content within the quotes-Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In my string:

```
str= 'a.ab.name:"so and so" and b.ab.id:"22" or b.ab.name:"some and some"';
```

I'm looking to group the string in this way:

```
str= 'a.ab:(name:"so and so") and b.ab.id:"22" or b.ab.name:"some and some"';
```

with regex:

```
/a\.ab\.((\S+?:\".+\")|([^<>=]+?\(.+?\))|.+?){1}($|(\s+?(and|or)\s+?))/ig
```

but instead I get this:

```
 str= 'a.ab:(name:"so) and so" and b.ab.id:"22" or b.ab.name:"some and some"';
```

because it checks for the first `and` and applies the closing brackets after it. Is there a way to check if the `and` or `or` is inside the `""` and if so dont apply the brackets inside the quotes.
A quick note: `name` and `id` fields are subject to change and is so is the query.
thanks for the help!

Comment: What should be your output string? grouping all `name` and `id`

Comment: o/p string: ```str= 'a.ab:(name:"so and so" ) and b.ab.id:"22" or b.ab.name:"some and some"';```